# MYSQL Test multiple dates in one record against a table with specific dates

Tags: mysql, date

FIrst time question so I will try and stay on point.

I have a system for recording staff attendance -
Tables:

- `tbl_Payperiod` - (ID, Payperiod, StartDate)
- `tbl_Rota` - (RotaID, PayperodID,EmployeeID, MonDate, Monstarttime, Monfinishtime, TuesDate, Tuesstarttime etc..)

The above works as I want it too and I can capture different variants of the working day e.g. annual leave, sickness etc.

The system is accessed through a browser using PHP (PHPRUNNER)

**The Question:** What I need to do is check if the date is a Public holiday.
I did this in previous setups in excel (using array and lookup) but I cannot figure out how to test it in MYSQL
I can create a table to hold the holiday dates and have this updated manually.
So how would I check and 'mark' the date in the `tbl_rota.MonPH = True or false`

Once I can 'mark' the date I can then apply the corresponding pay rate..
Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: Fix your schema!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left join `tbl_Rota` with the holidays table 7 times, once for each day of the week. Then set each `dayPH` field to true or false depending on whether the join was successful.

```
UPDATE tbl_Rota AS r
JOIN tbl_Holidays AS hMon ON r.MonDate = hMon.date
JOIN tbl_Holidays AS hTue ON r.TueDate = hTue.date
...
SET r.MonPH = hMon.date IS NOT NULL,
    r.TuePH = hTue.date IS NOT NULL,
    ...
```

Having separate columns in `tbl_Rota` for each day of the week really complicates this. If you had separate rows for each day, you could just do a single left join with the holiday table.

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried as you suggested but get error -probably not quite getting it..... The holiday table has 2 fields INT(autoincrement) and PHDate (holds the holiday date) so I list as you suggested changing the hREF to the corresponding day ....e.g. JOIN tbl_publicholidays AS hMon ON r.MonDate = hMon.PHDate
JOIN tbl_publicholidays AS hTue ON r.TuesDate = hTues.PHDate.....is that correct ?... when i do this i get error 1054 'unknown column'hTues.PHdate'...Thanks for assistance

Comment: OK Spotted my error need to change SET value to PHdate

Comment: Got it to run  - sorry but how do I set the value of r.MonPH to true if hMon.PHDate and rMonDate match... Again much appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 0):

A normalised approach might look a little like this:

```
RotaID, 
PayperodID,
EmployeeID

RotaID
Start_dt
Finish_dt
```